# delegate_to group with include_role runs command on local machine?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to debug a playbook I've written which uses a couple of roles to spin up and then configure an AWS instance.

The basic structure is one playbook (`new-server.yml`) imports two roles -- `roles/ec2_instance` and `roles/start_env`. The ec2_instance role should be ran on localhost with my AWS tokens and then the start_env role gets ran on servers which are generated by the first role.

My playbook `new-server.yml` starts off like this:

```
- name: provision new instance
  include_role:
    name: ec2_instance
    public: yes
  vars:
    instance_name: "{{ item.host_name }}"
    env: "{{ item.git_branch }}"
    env_type: "{{ item.env_type }}"
  loop:
    - { host_name: 'prod', git_branch: 'master', env_type: 'prod' }
    - { host_name: 'test', git_branch: 'test', env_type: 'devel'}
```

This role builds an ec2 instance, updates route 53, uses add_host to add the host to the in-memory inventory in the `just_created` group.

Next, I have this in the `new_server.yml` playbook. Both of my IPs show up here just fine. My localhost does not show up here.

```
- name: debug just_created group
  debug: msg="{{ groups['just_created'] }}"
```

Finally, again in `new_server.yml`, I try to do the last mile configuration and start my application on the new instance:

```
- name: Configure and start environment on new instance
  include_role:
    name: start_env
    apply:
      become: yes
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['just_created'] }}"
```

However, it doesnt look like the task is delegating properly, because I have this task in `roles/start_env/main.yml`:

```
- name: debug hostname
  debug: msg="{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

And what I'm seeing in my output is

```
TASK [start_env : debug hostname]   ************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 January 2021  12:00:05 -0800 (0:00:00.111)       0:00:37.374 ********
ok: [localhost -> 10.20.15.225] => {
    "msg": "My-Local-MBP"
}

TASK [start_env : debug hostname]     ************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 January 2021  12:00:05 -0800 (0:00:00.043)       0:00:37.417 ********
ok: [localhost -> 10.20.31.35] => {
    "msg": "My-Local-MBP"
}
```

I've read a lot about delegate_to, include_role and loops this morning. It sounds like Ansible has made things pretty complicated when you want to combine these things, but it also seems like the way I am trying to invoke these should be right. Any idea what I'm doing wrong (or if there is a smarter way to do this? I found [this](https://medium.com/opsops/ansible-2-5-delegate-to-and-include-role-20cd7e67008e) and while its a clever workaround, it doesn't quite fit what I'm seeing and I'd like to avoid creating another tasks file in my roles. Not exactly how I want to manage something like this. Most of the information I've been going off of has been this thread https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35398

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a known issue... the output shows `[localhost -> 10.20.31.35]`  which indicates it is delegating from `localhost` to `10.20.31.35`, however this is only for the connection.  Any templating done in the task definition uses the values of the host in the loop, which is `localhost`.

I figured out something in my own way that allows me to most keep what I've already written the same. I modified my add_host task to use the instance_name var as the hostname and the ec2 IP as the ansible_host instance var and then updated my last task to

roles/aws.yml:

```
- name: Add new instance to inventory
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ instance_name }}"
    ansible_host: "{{ ec2_private_ip }}"
    ansible_user: centos
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ../keys/my-key.pem
    groups: just_created
```

new_servers.yml:

```
tasks:

- name: provision new instance
  include_role:
    name: ec2_instance
    public: yes
  vars:
    instance_name: "{{ item.host_name }}"
    env: "{{ item.git_branch }}"
    env_type: "{{ item.env_type }}"
  loop:
    - { host_name: 'prod', git_branch: 'master', env_type: 'prod' }
    - { host_name: 'test', git_branch: 'test', env_type: 'devel'}
- name: Configure and start environment on new instance
  include_role:
    name: start_env
    apply:
      become: yes
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  vars:
    instance_name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['just_created'] }}"
```

Not pretty but it works well enough and lets me avoid duplicate code in the subsequent included roles.